# Use a block to set variables in parent scope

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

The gem [`binding_of_caller`](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller)  has an example for how to set a variable in a parent scope:

(this just pasted from their readme)

```
def a
  var = 10
  b
  puts var
end

def b
  c
end

def c
  binding.of_caller(2).eval('var = :hello')
end

a()

# OUTPUT
# => hello
```

This is useful, but it's limited by the need to do all variable initialization in a string.

I gave it a little thought and realized that I could use YAML to serialize/deserialize objects.

Take, for example, the following example:

```
def c
  value = YAML.dump [ { a: "b" } ]
  binding.of_caller(2).eval("var = YAML.load('#{value}')")
end

a()
# => {a: "b"}
```

This is cool, but it'd be better if I could avoid serialization altogether and just write a proper `do; end;` block like so:

```
# doesnt work
def c
  binding.of_caller(2).eval do
    # ideally this would set the variable named "var" in the scope of method "a"
    var = [ { a: "b" } ]
  end
end
```

How can I accomplish the functionality of this last example? I don't need to use `binding_of_caller` if there's another way.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Jordan I added an explicit question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best I could do and, I suspect (though I'd truly love to be proven wrong), the best you'll find short of writing your own C extension a la binding_of_caller:

```
require 'binding_of_caller'

module BindingExtensionEvalBlock
  def eval_block(&block)
    eval("ObjectSpace._id2ref(%d).call(binding)" % block.object_id)
  end
end

class ::Binding
  include BindingExtensionEvalBlock
end
```

The magic is here, of course:

```
eval("ObjectSpace._id2ref(%d).call(binding)" % block.object_id)
```

We get the object ID of the Proc and then, in our `Binding#eval`, use [`ObjectSpace#_id2ref`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-_id2ref) to retrieve it from wherever it is in memory and call it, passing in the local `binding`.

Here it is in action:

```
def a
  var = 10
  b
  puts var
end

def b
  c
end

def c
  binding.of_caller(2).eval_block do |bnd|
    bnd.local_variable_set(:var, [ { a: "b" } ])
  end
end

a # => {:a=>"b"}
```

As you can see, instead of `var = [ { a: "b" } ]` in our block we must do `bnd.local_variable_set(:var, [ { a: "b" } ])`. There's no way to change the binding of a block in Ruby, so we have to pass in a binding (`bnd`) and call [`Binding#local_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set).